# How do I get contents inside an XML Node as String in Java

Tags: java

I am looking for something like this :

```
<Node1>
   <Child2 attr1="abc">
   <Child3 attr2="xyz">
<Node1>
```

From Node1 , I want to get the contents inside the node as text. The output I want is

```
"<Child2 attr1="abc"><Child3 attr2="xyz">"
```

Comment: That XML is not formatted properly.. Have you tried searching the web for a java xml parser?

Comment: that was a mistype.my xml is the following 
<Node1>
   <Child2 attr1 = "abc" />
   <Child3 attr2 = "xyz" />
</Node1>

Answer (score 1):

```
   //Parse the input document
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new File("yourfile.xml"));

        //Set up the transformer to write the output string
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty("indent", "yes");
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);

        //Find the first child node 
        NodeList nl = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
        DOMSource source = null;
        for(int x = 0;x < nl.getLength();x++)
        {
            Node e = nl.item(x);
            if(e instanceof Element)
            {
                source = new DOMSource(e);
                break;
            }
        }

        transformer.transform(source, result);
        System.out.println(sw.toString());
    }
}
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632043/how-do-i-extract-child-element-from-xml-to-a-string-in-java) with other possible answers.